# bash script Rows to Columns

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

How can I change a file which is like this:

```
A   25
B   26
A   14
D   39
E   42

A   74
B   36
A   81
D   96
E   17

A   23
B   14
A   74
D   87
E   17
```

into a file with the rows as columns, but only once, and their according values in columns? Like this:

```
 A   B     A   D    E
25   26   14   39  42
74   36   81   96  17
23   14   74   87  17
```

My columns are repeated every 29 rows and some columns, like A, have the same name.

Comment: Have you made any attempt?

Comment: The last two days is the only thing that I'm doing :)

Comment: Don't *tell* us you made an attempt; *show* us the attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` script to transform the file:

*transform.awk:*

```
{
    # On the first record this loop runs twice. once
    # for the headers once for the first line of data.
    # In all subsequent lines is prints only the data
    # because h==1.
    for(;h<=1;h++){
        for(i=1+h;i<=NF;i+=2){
            printf "%s ", $i
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    h=1
}
```

Then execute it like this:

```
awk -f transform.awk RS='' file
```

Output:

```
A B A D E 
25 26 14 39 42 
74 36 81 96 17 
23 14 74 87 17
```

To get proper aligned columns you can pipe to `column -t`:

```
awk -f transform.awk RS='' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
A   B   A   D   E
25  26  14  39  42
74  36  81  96  17
23  14  74  87  17
```

The key here is the usage of the variable `RS` (*record separator*). Using an empty string for `RS` separates records by blank lines. It is the same as setting it to `\n\n+` (one or more blank lines). The first record for examples will look like this:

```
A   25
B   26
A   14 
D   39
E   42
```

`awk` by default splits by `[[:space:]]+` which includes newlines. This gives us the following fields for record one.

```
A 25 B 26 A 14 D 39 E 42
```

The algorithm shown above transforms this fields to the desired output.

Comment: Thank you hek2mgl for your answer but I'm getting: column: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, input like `\n\n\n+` works as well with `RS=''`!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Not sure if I use unicode locale. I suppose your answer is correct but I cannot verify it now on this laptop. I will try it tomorrow in another machine and I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much for your time and effort @hek2mgl

Comment: @jimakos17 You are welcome. What does `echo $LANG` give you?

Comment: en_US.UTF-8 @hek2mgl I connected to another machine and just reproduced it. Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: This works for me, well done, here it is as a oneliner: `awk -v RS='' '{for(;h<2;h++){for(i=1+h;i<=NF;i+=2){printf "%s ",$i}printf "\n"}h=1}' data.txt`

Answer (score 2):

alternative to `awk` solution with other unix toolset (used extensively)

```
$ sed '/^$/d' file    | 
  pr -3ts' '          | 
  tr '\t' ' '         | 
  tr -s ' '           | 
  cut -d' ' -f1,2,4,6 | 
  tr ' ' '\n'         | 
  pr -5ts' '          |
  column -t



A   B   A   D   E
25  26  14  39  42
74  36  81  96  17
23  14  74  87  17
```

first magic number `3` is number of repeated sections (or number of rows without header) and second magic number `5` is number of items in each section (or number of columns)

Answer (score 1):

For fun, some opaque, perl-ish ruby:

```
ruby -00 -lane '
    headers, values = $F.each_with_index.partition {|(v,i)| i.even?}
    puts headers.collect(&:first).join(" ") if $. == 1
    puts values.collect(&:first).join(" ")
' file
```

Comment: Cool! nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

And just to round out the mix, you can do it in a fairly flexible manner with a simple script (limited to reading 2-column files formatted as your input file is shown) It will read the data from a filename given as the first argument (or from `stdin` by default).

The script simply reads column-1 and column-2 into separate indexed arrays (`a1` & `a2`) until a blank line is encountered, and, if it is the first time through, prints the heading row (and sets the heading flag `h` to not print again), followed by printing the data in `a2`.

When the end of the file is reached is simply prints the final row of data.

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

declare -i h=0
declare -a a1
declare -a a2

while read -r line; do
    if [ "$line" != "" ]; then
        a1+=( ${line%% *} )
        a2+=( ${line##* } )
    else 
        [ "$h" -eq 0 ] && { printf " %2s" ${a1[@]}; echo ""; h=1; }
        printf " %2s" ${a2[@]}
        echo ""
        unset a1; unset a2;
    fi
done < "$fname"

printf " %2s" ${a2[@]}
echo ""
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash r2c.sh dat/r2c.txt
  A  B  A  D  E
 25 26 14 39 42
 74 36 81 96 17
 23 14 74 87 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a litle bit more reg-exp oriented:

```
perl -0pE  'say s/\s*\d+\h*\n|\n.*/ /sgr;  s/(^|\n)\w\s*/ /g' file
```